# elcimagepickercontroller in swift

Tags: swift, elcimagepickercontroller

I am using xcode 7.2 and Swift 2.1.1. I am using ELCImagePickerController through bridging header. When I use ELCImagePickerControllerDelegate in class declaration,it shows error- the viewcontroller does not conform to protocol 'ELCImagePickerControllerDelegate'

`let picker = ELCImagePickerController()
        picker.maximumImagesCount = 5

        picker.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)`

This is my objective c header `#import "ELCImagePickerController.h"`

When I use this code on button click event it goes to empty view and not the gallery.Can anyone help me to overcome this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ELCImagePickerController is in objective c and you want to use in Swift?

Comment: Yes and I am using bridging header.

Comment: Does your bridging file contain #import "ELCImagePickerController" ?

Comment: Does it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error -** the viewcontroller does not conform to protocol 'ELCImagePickerControllerDelegate' because you have to implement below 2 delegate methods which are mandatory. ( Not optional )

```
func elcImagePickerController(picker: ELCImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [AnyObject]!) {
    
}


func elcImagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: ELCImagePickerController!) {
    
}
```

[Download whole working project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKb3ptYUQ0TG1zRjQ/view?usp=sharing)

**Working code**

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, ELCImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var picker = ELCImagePickerController(imagePicker: ())
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }

    
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        
        picker.maximumImagesCount = 5
        picker.imagePickerDelegate = self
        self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        
    }
    
    func elcImagePickerController(picker: ELCImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [AnyObject]!) {
        
    }
    
    
    func elcImagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: ELCImagePickerController!) {
        
    }
   
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**That black screen were coming because of**

```
var picker = ELCImagePickerController()
```

**Proper way is**

```
var picker = ELCImagePickerController(imagePicker: ())
```

Comment: It worked perfectly...Thank you very much for your timely help.

Comment: Welcome. Have a happy coding.